# Are the statements about the conditional probability true?

Tags: probability

Let $P$ be a probability measure on a $\sigma$-Algebra $\mathcal{A}$. I want to prove or disprove the following statement:

- $P(C\mid A)>P(C\mid A\cup B)$, for $A, B, C\in \mathcal{A}$ with $C\subset A\cap B$ and $P(B\setminus A)>0$

$$$$

I have done the following:

- We have that $P(C\mid A)=\frac{P(C\cap A)}{P(A)}$ and $P(C\mid A\cup B)=\frac{P(C\cap (A\cup B))}{P(A\cup B)}$.

  We have that $C\cap (A\cup B)=(C\cap B)\cup (C\cap B)$. Since $C\subset A\cap B$ these two sets are not disjoint, therefore we get $P(C\cap (A\cup B))=P((C\cap A)\cup (C\cap B))<P(C\cap A)+P(C\cap B)$, right?

  It holds that $P(A\cup B)>P(A)\Rightarrow \frac{1}{P(A\cup B)}<\frac{1}{P(A)}$.

  Therefore we get $P(C\mid A\cup B)=\frac{P(C\cap (A\cup B))}{P(A\cup B)}<\frac{P(C\cap A)+P(C\cap B)}{P(A)}$.

  Is everything correct so far? How could we continue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, all you need is that *because* $C\subset A\cap B$ , *therefore* $C\subset A$ , $C\subset B$ , and $C\subset A\cup B$.

Also if $C\subset X$ , then $C=C\cap X$.

---

So

> It holds that since $P(A\cup B)>P(A)$ (why?), so therefore $\frac{1}{P(A\cup B)}<\frac{1}{P(A)}$.

Thus $\frac{P(C)}{P(A\cup B)}<\frac{P(C)}{P(A)}$, and hence...

Comment: Ah so we have that $P(C\mid A\cup B)=\frac{P(C\cap (A\cup B))}{P(A\cup B)}=\frac{P(C)}{P(A\cup B)}<\frac{P(C)}{P(A)}=\frac{P(C\cap A)}{P(A)}$ since $P(A\cup B)>P(A)\Rightarrow \frac{1}{P(A\cup B)}<\frac{1}{P(A)}$, right?

Comment: Could you give me a hint how we could prove that $P(A\cup B)>P(A)$ ? I got stuck right now.

Comment: @MaryStar Hmmm... You need a hint to prove that $P(A\cup B)>P(A)$ when $P(B\setminus A)\ne0$? Are you sure?

Comment: We have that $A\cup B = A\cup (B\setminus A)$ and the sets $A$ and $(B\setminus A)$ are disjoint. 

So, we get that $P(A\cup B)=P(A\cup (B\setminus A)) = P(A)+P (B\setminus A)>P(A)+0=P(A)$. 

Therefore, we have that $P(A\cup B)>P(A)$. 

Is this correct? @Did

Comment: @MaryStar Yes. $ $